# Why does javascript canvas2d clipping require a path?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, draw, clip

I was pulling my hair out over this bug for a while.  I wanted to render images in three sections of a canvas, without allowing them to overlap. Basically, I wanted to use `canvas.getContext('2d').clip()` to keep the images separated. However, the clip only works if I call `canvas.getContext('2d').beginPath()` after I draw the image.

So this does not work (no clip is applied):

```
    this.draw=function(image, cx, cy, width, height, clip){
        var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rect(clip.x, clip.y, clip.width, clip.height);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(clip.x, clip.y, clip.width, clip.height);
        ctx.drawImage(image,cx-width/2,cy-height/2,width,height);
        ctx.restore();
        return this;
    };
```

But this does:

```
    this.draw=function(image, cx, cy, width, height, clip){
        var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rect(clip.x, clip.y, clip.width, clip.height);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(clip.x, clip.y, clip.width, clip.height);
        ctx.drawImage(image,cx-width/2, cy-height/2,width,height);
        ctx.beginPath();// <------WITCHCRAFT
        ctx.restore();
        return this;
    };
```

It was a total accident that I discovered that `beginPath()` fixes the problem, and I have no idea why. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Not witchcraft that is the way you tell the context you are starting a new path and done with the old path.  BTW the beginPath should go just before you create a path (just after `ctx.save()` in your code). Just luck it worked because if you had used ctx.arc instead of fillRect it would have added the arc to the clip.

Comment: I'm still confused, in the documentation for [rect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect), it says that the sub-path is marked as closed. Also, if I replace the fillRect line with `ctx.arc(256,256,512,0,3.1416*2, true);`, the clipping still works (512x512 canvas).  To be fair, it does still work if I move it to just after save();.

Comment: In large part I'm baffled that beginPath() seems to travel through time.  It can't be used for the clipping path, because that's done with.  It can't be used for the image, because that's done with too.  It's as if the clip instruction is only applied after a path is started, but once it's started, it can retroactively clip images that have already been drawn since clip call.

Comment: Having tested the code you provided it works in both cases, with and without the beginPath. If all things in the function have been eliminated then that cause must be elsewhere. You must have a existing path on the canvas. Get context does not reset paths, pahs are pat of the canvas not context, The basics rule is always start setting out a clip area with beginPath, if you dont then the behaviour can become unpredictable if the canvas is not a new one.

Comment: It's good practice to start a clip with beginPath?  Yeah, it looks like [you're right](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-clip-function.html).  I would say this is what I get for using [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp), but [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) didn't mention this either. These kinda 'gotchas' drive me nuts.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Because clipping requires a path? Perhaps you missed it in the documentation. Here's what MDN documentation says:

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.clip() method of the Canvas 2D API turns the **path** currently being built into the current clipping path.

(emphasis mine)

The reason it needs a path is because clipping mask can be any arbitrary shape from rectangles to circles to the outline of Pikachu.

---

For the sake of completeness, here's what the W3C spec says about `.clip()`:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#drawing-paths-to-the-canvas

> context . clip()
>   Further constrains the clipping region to the current path.

Comment: Isn't there already a path? perhaps you missed it in the question. Here's what the code snippet says: `ctx.rect(clip.x, clip.y, clip.width, clip.height);ctx.clip();`  The reason this doesn't help is because the path code was there in both cases.  For the sake of completeness, here's what the W3C spec says about `rect()`: [creates a path for a rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect)